# Updating java 8 to java 17

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, java-17

I am new to microservice world, I am upgrading eureka discovery service from java 8 to java 17. I changed the spring boot version along with spring cloud dependencies. When I navigated to eureka dashboard, eureka environment and data center property is showing as N/A. [image]

Note: I am using java 17, spring boot version 2.5.7 and spring cloud dependencies version 2020.0.4.
Am I missing something here.

Comment: Please commit more information about the project, such as key code, log, config, etc.

Comment: @SheldonWei I degraded the java version and spring cloud dependencies. Netflix eureka dependency is having bug, so those properties were not displayed as expected (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/4032).